# Select specific columns from table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, select, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to select specific columns from a table like this:

```
users = Table('users', metadata, autoload=True)
s = users.select([users.c.email])
results = s.execute()
print results
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "my_mailer.py", line 35, in
> <module>
>     s = users.select([users.c.email])   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 175, in select
>     return Select([self], whereclause, **params)   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 2082, in __init__
>     self._whereclause = _literal_as_text(whereclause)   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 2745, in
> _literal_as_text
>     "SQL expression object or string expected." sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string
> expected.
```

So I tried this:

```
users = Table('users', metadata, autoload=True)
s = users.select('email')
results = s.execute()
print results
```

And got this in response:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "my_mailer.py", line 36, in
> <module>
>     results = s.execute()   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 124, in execute
>     return e._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1605, in
> _execute_clauseelement
>     return connection._execute_clauseelement(elem, multiparams, params)   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 761,
> in _execute_clauseelement
>     compiled_sql, distilled_params   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 874, in
> _execute_context
>     context)   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1023, in _handle_dbapi_exception
>     exc_info   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 185, in raise_from_cause
>     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 867, in
> _execute_context
>     context)   File "/task/__pips__/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 388, in do_execute
>     cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) argument of WHERE
> must be type boolean, not type character varying LINE 3: WHERE email
```

Sure enough, the first argument here is the 'whereclause', not 'columns' like everywhere else, this is reflected in [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html):

> This argument is not present on the form of select() available on
>   Table.

**Question:** how can I select only specific columns using select on the table? And generally, why on earth the columns argument is not available on *select* on the table? I can't understand why somebody made the decision to make this different than the standard *select*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use general purpose [`select`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) instead of [`Table.select`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.select):

```
stmt = select([users.c.email])
result = conn.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: I know that I can do this, but do you know if there is any way of doing the same with the table select flavour? Not being able to do the same with the table select renders it defective in my opinion.

Comment: Read the second link of the documentation: it is explicit about it: no, you cannot do it. In a way `table.select` is just a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 16):

With metadata you can do this:

```
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
tblusers = metadata.tables['users']
tblproducts = metadata.tables['products']
# example 1: only columns you want.
data_users = tblusers.select().with_only_columns([tblusers.c.id, tblusers.c.name]).execute()
# example 2: w/ where & order_by
data_products = tblproducts.select().with_only_columns([tblproducts.c.id, tblproducts.c.price, tblproductos.c.description]).where(tblproducts.c.stock > 0).order_by(tblproducts.c.brand).execute()
```

Be well...

[SqlAlchemy Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html?highlight=columns#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns)